# Flex iOS IP Dialog Box

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I am making an app for iOS using the flex SDK. When I build a version of the app and run it on my iphone 4S it works fine but when I click on a certain button it keeps asking me for an ip address.

I have **NOT** compiled in debug mode. It is a different type of pop-up also which I am not able to see it fully. Any idea what could cause the pop-up?

Comment: I don't really know enough to answer your question, but maybe a screenshot could help those who can?

Comment: http://i41.tinypic.com/350qmib.png

Here's a link of the error

Comment: it seems to be happening on android as well

Comment: I am having the same problem, if you find an answer please post it.

Answer (score 1):

The pop-up is the app looking for the host ip to debug

I found more of a workaround than a fix:
Exporting a release build will remove the popup, it might take more time though

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what my issue is in my somewhat more detailed question   [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969210/web-service-network-issue-on-android-using-flex/12034945#12034945)

It's important to note this does not happen when testing using my internal wifi connection as the connection to the test computer is available (this is the IP in the box). To avoid the issue use this version of the ipa instead. Otherwise do not worry it will not be present in the final release build.

```
Project --> Export Release Build
```